# transition in multiple animation

Tags: flash, animation

We are trying to create a few game animations in Adobe flash. We face a problem with animation transition.

We import characters AI file to flash, and animate it. Character has different animation, so we do it multiple times.

The problem is, even though we import the same file, the frame png files are a little different in size. This makes transition from animation to animation jerky.

How can I create this in proper way in flash.